# Hash Aggregate on C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, stl

I was trying to implement a hash aggregate algorithm in C++.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
for each input row
  begin
    calculate hash value on group by column(s)
    check for a matching row in the hash table // calculate hash function **(A)**
    if we do not find a match
      insert a new row into the hash table // calculate hash function again? **(B)**
    else
      update the matching row with the input row
  end
output all rows in the hash table
```

Using the STL (C++) the line **A** is: `iter_type it=groupByMap.find(hashKey);`
So i will pay a find, calculating the hash value.

The line **B** will be: `it = groupByMap.insert(it, newHashElement);`
So i pay **again** a find, calculating the hash value.

Is there any way to perform only one hash calculation?

Comment: What's the type of `groupByMap`?

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Just use [insert version (2) as listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) and it will return you a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`... the `bool` says whether it had to isnert or found an existing match, and with the iterator you can modify the match without searching again (and therefore without hashing again).

Comment: Thanks Tony!!! It works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asssume that `groupByMap` is `std::unordered_map<YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE>` and it is typedefed as `YourMap`.

If so, just do:

```
std::pair<YourMap::iterator, bool> position = 
    groupByMap.emplace(hashKey, newHashElement);
if (!position.second)
{
  // Insertion didn't occur, a key was already there, so just update contents.
  YourUpdate(*position.first);
}
```

In the above code I used `emplace()` method of `std::unordered_map`. `groupByMap.emplace(hashKey, newHashElement)` is essentially `groupByMap.insert(std::make_pair(hashKey, newHashElement))` but without creating a temporary pair (it constructs pair in place). So if you didn't use `std::unordered_map` but some other class, like `stl::hash_map`, which does not have `emplace()`, you can replace `emplace()` with `insert()` as described, it will work OK.